# Least expensive operation to check for new records in table with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have PostgreSQL running together with EF7.

My table structure:

- Id (bigint)
- Content (text)
- CreatedAt (timestamp without time zone NOT NULL)

I have infinite scroll in my frontend app and query results with .Skip(n) & .Take(m). 
I.e.

```
.Skip(0), .Take(10); 
.Skip(10), .Take(10);
.Skip(20), .Take(10);
<...>
```

Now, while scrolling, if there're newer records, I have to know how many and add them to .Skip(n) function. I don't need to display them, just need to add them to consideration while skipping.

Currently I'm checking for them like so but this seemingly should be quite expensive after table will exceed 50k-100k records:

```
_myRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.CreatedAt > newestActivityDate).Count();
```

GetAll():

```
public IQueryable<Activity> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Activities.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
}
```

What would be the best (most performant) operation to check whether there're new records & how many? Checking by date and only then doing count if there're any new records?

EDIT: 
Added GetAll() description for more clarity.

Comment: Does `GetAll()` returns `IQueryable`?

Comment: Yes, GetAll() returns IQueryable

Comment: If you always know "newestActivityDate" - one option is to just limit your queries with Where(x => c.CreatedAt <= newestActivityDate). Then checking for new records will become unnecessary.

Comment: Then it shouldn't be that expensive, the generated SQL would be using `COUNT()` and that is relatively fine (unless you want to denormalize and save the counter elsewhere)

Comment: @Evk that could be option, yes, but besides just querying older results, I also want to know whether there are actually new activities and if there're, to show a nice label saying just that. :)

Comment: Well then your method seems fine enough. If you have proper index on CreatedAt column - your counts should be fast, without scanning whole table. But do you call your method by timer, periodically? By the way now when you added GetAll definition - you don't need to do order by before doing Count(), so just do _context.Activities.Where(...).Count().

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your `.GetAll()` method does, so that really is the crux of your problem.

LINQ has what is called [deferred execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693185.aspx). What that means is that the query will not get executed until the results are acted upon. So in the case of when you're building a SQL query, nothing will get sent to the database until you finish with it.

So if your `.GetAll()` method queries with a `.ToList()` in there, then it will pull everything from the database immediately before adding the rest of your filtering. In that case, yes, it will be very expensive.

However, you can get around that by just asking for the count. You already have most of that set up.

If you add a new method in your repository like this:

```
public int GetNewRecordsCount(DateTime newestActivityDate)
{
    _context.Widgets.Count(x => x.CreatedAt > newestActivityDate);
}
```

Then this will create a different SQL query that is just something similar to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Widgets
WHERE CreatedAt > newestActivityDate;
```

That is a very quick operation where the database will do all of the filtering for you. The only thing returned to your code is just a single row, single column result of the total count.

Comment: `Count` can take a criteria and you don't need `Where` at all :D

Comment: Thanks. It's a day off, and I just woke up.

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to contribute with that enhancement to your answer ;)

Comment: It could be. It doesn't necessarily help. 50-100k records isn't *that* much. Run some tests with and without the index. Don't forget to test insert, update, and delete speeds as well since all of those are also affected by having indexes.